# Get dot separated path of a standard library function from the function itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, standard-library

Is there a way to get a full name (dot separated path of a function including its name) of a standard library function? For example:

```
import sys
import os
from random import choice

my_function = choice([sys.exit, os.path.join, os.getcwd])

print(my_function) # Somehow generate full name of the built-in function
# Would expect to get one of 'sys.exit', 'os.path.join' or 'os.getcwd'
```

Comment: What would you do with such a function?

Comment: Would store human readable log, which function was called.

Comment: Downvoting without any explanation? Please let me know whats wrong with this question. I have already fixed the wrong tagging (changed `builtin` to `standard-library`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the information you're looking for using the `__module__` and `__qualname__` attributes of a function (under Python 3).  For example:

```py
>>> import sys
>>> func = sys.exit
>>> print('{}.{}'.format(func.__module__, func.__qualname__))
sys.exit
```

This also works for class members:

```py
>>> import email.message

>>> func = email.message.Message.get_payload
>>> print('{}.{}'.format(func.__module__, func.__qualname__))
email.message.Message.get_payload
```

It's a little more work under Python 2.x because the `__qualname__` attribute isn't available:

```py
>>> print('{}.{}.{}'.format(func.__module__, func.im_class.__name__, func.__name__))
```

Comment: For `os.path.join` I get `"posixpath.join"`, however I would expect `"os.path.join"`.

Comment: `os.path` is a bad test case, because that actually ends up being `posixpath` or `macpath` or `ntpath`, etc., depending on the platform. So you're actually getting the correct answer.

Comment: It is strange that you have chose to use `func.__qualname__` instead of `func.__name__`. Whats the difference?

Comment: Compare the output of `email.message.Message.get_payload.__name__` and `email.message.Message.get_payload.__qualname__`.

Comment: So the `__name__` returns only the function name, e.g. `'get_payload'`, and `__qualname__` includes the class name too, e.g. `'Message.get_payload'`. Great! Thank you @larsks!